# Power server when power is on (No Bios access)

Tags: hardware, electrical-power, power-supply-unit

I have 3 servers and one is old hardware. I have frequent power outage due a Kw limit.

I know there is an option in the BIOS to power on a machine when there is power.
2 servers does have this AC Power Recovery option, but the last one I can access it since I don't have PS/2 keyboard.

Could there be an hardware solution to this?
I was thinking of an Arduino powered on an outlet that checks if detects power through the USB port of the server. If there's power, then wait else if there's no power send a signal to the `Power SW` pins on the MOBO?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Depends on the server hardware. Do you have any details?

Comment: I think it is a : Gigabyte Motherboard GA-P55-US3L

Comment: That's not a server

Answer (score 0):

If you also have modern hardware on that network. You could use that to send Wake on Lan packets. Most mobo's, even old ones support that, might be also called WoL.

Answer (score 0):

A server requires emergency power from a UPS, especially with frequent power outages. Getting hold of a PS/2 keyboard isn't really hard, lots of folks are giving them or throwing them away.

Of course you can build all kind of hardware workarounds for pressing the power switch. You should however check if you can't simply power up the server by sending a Wake-on-LAN packet - most servers support this (it may require activation in BIOS though).